# Error while writing Kotlin extension function

Tags: android, kotlin

Below is my extension:

```
fun String?.toDoubleOrDefault(): Double = this?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
```

when I try to apply it like this:

```
var a:String? = "1000"
var b:String? = "2000"
var c = a?.toDoubleOrDefault()*b?.toDoubleOrDefault()
```

I get this error:
Type mismatch.

Required:Double

Found:Double?

Could anyone please explain what I am Doing wrong?

Comment: Do `a.toDoubleOrDefault()*b.toDoubleOrDefault()`. No need for null check since you already do so in the method. This is also the reason why you're getting `Double?` as a return value from that call.

Comment: as a side note the extension function would be more flexible as : `fun String?.toDoubleOrDefault(defaultVal : Double = 0.0): Double = this?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: defaultVal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
    var a:String? = "1000"
    var b:String? = "2000"
    var c  = a.toDoubleOrDefault()*b.toDoubleOrDefault()
```